# xamarin 5.7 android connection to the layout renderer failed

Tags: android, visual-studio-2013, xamarin, xamarin-studio

I've installed Xamarin 5.7 (build 661).

I use Xamarin Android and I've run into a problem when I tried to use the designer in Visual Studio 2013 or Xaramin Studio

> Connection to the layout renderer failed. This may be caused by a misconfiguration of Java

I tried to downgrade the tools as mentionned [here](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/51784/#Comment_51784) but this time it did not work

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What I had to is to

- Install Java JDK 1.8. You can find it [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html)
- Uninstall Java JDK 1.6 and JDK 1.7 from the control panel in windows

Now, I can use the latest Android SDK tools (24.0.2 at this time)
[This is where I found the solution](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/98307/#Comment_98307)

Comment: with java jdk version 1.8 you did not have problems using "Publish Android Application" without any problem and you generated the .apk? that before was necessary to use jdk 1.6

Comment: I didn't have any problem when publishing my app. However, I had to install again jdk 1.6 to sign my app (for the keytool, I had a signature problem with an old android phone). However, when I installed jdk 1.6, I didn't have any problem with the android tool 24.0.2

Comment: For anyone else coming here: This may work, but is not always a good option. I need the older version of java for various other projects, so the the best solution is option 2 in the answer given by Yaircl.

Answer (score 4):

I find the previous answer too complicated. Of course it solves the problem, but there are 2 more possibilities that are twice faster:

**1)** Copy

"...\Xamarin Studio\AddIns\MonoDevelop.MonoDroid\java\AndroidDesigner.jar"

to

"...\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android\4.7.04014\java\AndroidDesigner.jar"

**OR**

**2)** Just clean the rebuild the project. Close Xamarin and open it again.

Answer (score 2):

Still yet another answer that worked for me w/o all the other stuff:

In Xamarin Studio go to Tools -> Options -> Projects -> SDK Locations -> Android and make sure that the Java SDK points to the 1.8 version (at the time of this writing). I still had Java SDK 1.6 and 1.7 installed and this worked without an issue.

Comment: It's worked for me on visual studio 2015. In visual studio 2015 goto `tools->option->scroll to xamarin->Android Serrings` here select the location of JDK 1.8, If you have 64bit version installed of java then look inside the folder `Program Files/Java` instead of `Program Files(x86)/Java/`.

Answer (score 0):

Just want to share my experience on this. I have just encountered this error when I have updated to the `xamarin 3.11.590` and, `java jre 7` and `java sdk 7`.

What I did was, I have updated to java jre and sdk to version 8 and, uninstall the `java jre` and sdk version 7 but, it still has that error. So, I have downgraded to `xamarin 3.11.586` and this solves my problem already.